# Software that would convert Google documents to .docx

Tags: google-apps, google-drive

Is there a way to convert a Document that you create in Google Docs to .docx or .odt?

Edit: To be more specific, I am looking for a software that would be able to archive this.

Edit: I want to implement automatic backup system that will backup files from Google Docs to USB device

Comment: I assume that software should run on Windows (going by .docx)? How much would you be willing to spend if it comes to paid solutions?

Comment: Well, either docx or odt. I would spend up to 100 € for personal use

Comment: @Izzy Word on the Mac also uses .docx.

Comment: That's why I asked to specify the targeted OS. But given the direct export functionality mentioned in Imus' answer, no software is needed here unless OP is asking for ODT specifically.

Comment: Your latest edit changes the question entirely. [See XY-problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) I don't fully understand why you would need to backup google files... google's backup is probably more reliable than your own USB-backups anyway and it's possible to look at previous versions in case you're affraid someone might delete the content ...

Answer (score 4):

In google docs choose File > download > Microsoft Word (.docx)

Edit: For completeness sake, also supports other formats as well.

[image]